# Are different implementations of abstract method viewable as overriding?

Tags: java, abstract, overriding

Method overriding means different implementations of the supertype method in the the subtypes.If we have an abstract method then we must implement that each time a class extends the class containing the abstract method. Isn't it similar to method overriding?

Comment: It *is* overriding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) uses the term "overriding" for this:

> If a non-abstract method mC overrides an abstract method mA from a class C, then mC is said to implement mA from C.

The word override is used here as including the case of implementing an abstract method. Implementing is described as a specialized case of overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely. If you extend a class that has a method with a *method body*, you **may** override the method, whereas if the method is abstract, you **must** either implement (*Override*) it or declare the subclass itself abstract.

An abstract method does not have a *method body*.

Comment: But different classes that are implementing that abstract method do indeed making different implementation each time they implement.The argument of not having method body does not seem valid to me.Please explain further.

Comment: It is essentially the same. In both cases you *are* overriding a method: It doesn't matter if the method is abstract or not. So one may write `@Overrides` in both examples. The difference between an abstract and a non-abstract method is explained in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an abstract method is not overriding IMHO, although the `@Override` annotation may be used.

An *implementation* can be overridden. A subclass of a concrete class that has *implemented* an abstract method can override the concrete class's implementation, but at that point the method being implemented is not abstract anymore.

Comment: So if I have a class that extends abstract class and also implements an interface that the abstract class implements as well.In the interface I have an abstract method, my abstract class implements that abstract method and my concrete class also implements that method.Then what it would be; the concrete class implements that abstract method from the interface or it overrides the abstract method from the abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

It's overriding.

Proof:

```
abstract public class Shape {
    public abstract void draw();
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    @Override // this does not fail!
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("I am square!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = new Square();
        s.draw();
    }
}
```

Had this *not* been overriding, use of `@Override` should have been flagged by the compiler (annotation processor) as an error.